# Compress large python objects

Tags: python, memory, numpy, compression

I am trying to compress a huge python object ~15G, and save it on the disk. Due to requrement constraints I need to compress this file as much as possible. I am presently using zlib.compress(9). My main concern is the memory taken exceeds what I have available on the system 32g during compression, and going forward the size of the object is expected to increase. Is there a more efficient/better way to achieve this.
Thanks.

Update: Also to note the object that I want to save is a sparse numpy matrix, and that I am serializing the data before compressing, which also increases the memory consumption. Since I do not need the python object after it is serialized, would gc.collect() help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Incremental (de)compression should be done with `zlib.{de,}compressobj()` so that memory consumption can be minimized. Additionally, higher compression ratios can be attained for most data by using `bz2` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The memLevel parameter of `deflateInit2 ()` specifies how much memory should be allocated for the internal compression state. The default is `8`, the maximum is `9` and the minimum is `1` (see the [zlib manual](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html)). If you've already tried that or it doesn't help you enough, it might be necessary to look at another compression algorithm or library instead.